# Got error in multiste ( Domain access module )

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-domain-access

With few information about domain access module, i installed in my site, Am not aware how to

manage content for multiple site,

main site : http://happylife.in (drupal installed here)

Sub domain http://devotional.happylife.in (i am not installed drupal here, simply index.php)

while posting selected domain is http://devotional.happylife.in

But i am getting Error,

**Internal Server Error**
i am not sure, how drupal will show this content in http://devotional.happylife.in

without any installation in sub domain,

For your reference check this site,

http://happylife.in,click this article, **about Venkateswara Temples.**

Now page redirect to http://devotional.happylife.in/node/32 ,

and displaying  Error **Internal Server Error**

How to handle content for mutiple site in domain access module.

what steps i should follow,

advise me

Answer (score 0):

I think you've configured your virtual hosts improperly. The domain module works by [pointing one or more domains at a single Drupal instance](http://drupal.org/node/1096954), rather than copying Drupal into separate file structures.

In your example you need to make certain that happylife.in and devotional.happylife.in are both pointing at the same Drupal installation.

For reference, [the complete documentation for Domain Access](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/domain).

Comment: if i share the table, then b site not using the its own table, .